# Savepoints without ./bin/flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

1. Is it possible to run a job from a savepoint having a direct
   main() + LocalExecutionEnvironment setup?
2. Is it possible to do that through Remote*Environment?
3. Is it possible to do that or trigger a savepoint via ClusterClient?
4. Is the above possible through the rest api? Web ui (doesn't look like that)?
5. Finally, Is it possible to perform savepoint operations from local ./bin/flink against a remote cluster (same version but maybe different OS)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer partially (3) you can do that using a `ClusterClient` by doing something similar to:

```
final Configuration config = GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration("...");
final ClusterClient client = new StandaloneClusterClient(config);

final PackagedProgram packagedProgram = new PackagedProgram(new File(FLINK_JOB_JAR));
packagedProgram.setSavepointRestoreSettings(SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath("...", true));

client.run(packagedProgram, 1);
```